# Schedule DynamoDb to S3 dumps every 15 min

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a use case where I frequently need to move data from DynamoDb to S3. I know that AWS Glue has an exporter option, however I haven’t seen it written anywhere that it’s performant at such frequent intervals.

The context is that I have a production application where I frequently need to take data from source A (dynamo) and data from source B (S3) join and transform on very frequent intervals.

Comment: Do you want the entire table exported every 15 minutes? How large is the table?

Comment: Fair question! It’s about 300k rows so low-medium in terms of size and due to business reasons won’t be changing in size

Comment: Why do you need to do it every 15 minutes? Why not use Dynamodb streams with a Lambda and do it ad-hoc?

Comment: The transformed values we’re after are constraints in an optimization model. After 15 min of staleness, the optimization model decreases in performance very rapidly.

Comment: Ideally, you'd do this incrementally using DynamoDB Streams but that's not ideal when the target is S3 (where objects cannot be updated and can only be replaced). If you haven't, look at options for [managed export to S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/S3DataExport.HowItWorks.html). Key thing is that it's faster than scan and it doesn't use table capacity (it works off PITR afaik) so won't affect the performance or availability of the underlying table.

Comment: In looking into DDB streams right now, thanks! About source B, the longer context is that I also want it in DynamoDb. However this data originates in redshift. The intermediate spot I’ve gotten it to is in S3, but I’m working on a lambda function to move it to DDB. Fortunately this source is only populated once daily.